# XSLT or JAXB which one to use

Tags: java, xslt, jaxb

I want to transform one XML to another xml. What will be the best way to do that. I searched on net and found i could use XSLT or JAXB to do that. Can anybody help in fidning what will be  the best practice.

Answer (score 4):

If you try to do this in JAXB, you will be converting XML into Java objects and then back to XML. That can be useful if you really want to take advantage of the Java objects, but if you just want XML-to-XML then it's pointless to have something non-XML in the middle. You haven't described the transformation, but in most cases XSLT will be the right tool for the job. It's only disadvantage is that there's a learning curve: it's probably rather different from the programming or scripting language that you're familiar with, being rule-based and declarative. Spend a day reading a good book before you start coding, and you are much more likely to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Lets say if in xml parent has childs. So i want to extract child and replace parent with parent+childs(new parents with different sub id)

Comment: @bhaskaragr29 - That's exactly the type of thing XSLT was designed to make easy.

Answer (score 0):

You use JAXB if you want to bind Java Classes to XML and vice versa. If you just want to transform XML -> XML then XSLT is the way to go.

Google for JAXP (Java API for XML Processing), in particular the TransformerFactory-Class should give you a good starting-point.

Answer (score 0):

Read this on XSLT in java : www.oreilly.com/catalog/javaxslt/chapter/ch05.html

JAXB is used for XML binding (i.e. serialize your classes as XML).

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, xslt can be *very* slow. if the file is small, try a dom parser otherwise a sax parser.

Comment: There is no reason why XSLT should be slow unless it is badly written. Most XSLT transformations are dominated by the time used to parse the input and serialize the output, which are costs that you incur whatever language the transformation is written in.